# LINQ to SQL - Problem with 1-to-1 association

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, oop, orm

In the L2S designer I have dropped a table and a view. I tried adding an association between the 2 on their primary keys. This should be a one-to-one relationship, so I set the cardinality property of the association as such.

But, when coding I can't access the child property.

Any suggestions?

## Edit

I just created a view in sql server that has the fields I want, and dropped that into L2S. Much simpler.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using, it'll make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: You want the l2s designer code? DBML xml? C# code consuming the data context? That's a lot of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience Linq To SQL requires the Primary/Foreign key relationships established in the DB.  Otherwise, you'll have to do a join.

Not sure if this applies to your situation, but it may...

[Linq To SQL Without Explicit Foreign Key Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619231/linq-to-sql-without-explicit-foreign-key-relationships)

**UPDATE:**

It appears that you can get what you're looking for without establishing the Primary/Foreign key relationships in the database.  In the LinqToSQL designer set primary keys on both columns on each table.  I also had to turn off Auto-Sync on Parent Table's column that I assigned as a primary key.

Auto-Sync is described here.. 
*Instructs the common language runtime (CLR) to retrieve the value after an insert or update operation.*

Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386971.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem with views.
We simply defined the keys in the DBML editor and the property was finally defined.

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable (set to false) either the child or parent property?

Did you perhaps mapped the one-to-one relationship the wrong way around (like I did less than an hour ago)?

Comment: Child property is true. I have tried both objects as the parent.

Comment: Look in the .designer file for the property you expect. Perhaps you have another property that is clashing or something like that.